# Some questions on this site have duplicates on AskUbuntu

Tags: discussion

elementary OS is based on Ubuntu so Ubuntu problems also happen on elementary. This site has issues with graphics drivers which apply also to Ubuntu. Questions not related to Ubuntu are related to `wingpanel`, `slingshot`, `scratch` etc and other elementary programs.

Comment: Just because the questions are identical does not mean the procedure for solving them is. For instance theme issues might also appear on Ubuntu, but we use a later Gtk version. I'm not entirely sure what your question is though.

Comment: @LewisGoddard exaclty. As for what the question is, on Meta, it doesn't have to be a question. It can be a statement or a feature request, even an *acceptable* "rant".

Comment: @LewisGoddard Newer Ubuntu versions including needed GTK.I think this site should b about elementary programs such as wingpanel scratch etc

Comment: Anything you see on https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+index is our packages. Several of those are in Ubuntu too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this logic, if a problem occurs on Fedora, you should ask on a Red Hat forum how to solve it, because Fedora is technically just RHEL minus a few proprietary features.